# nodejs how I filter an arrays of objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, object

i have a list of arrays an objects like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: true
    }
  ]
]
```

Now I want filter all objects where listed is true but it doesnt work, i tried the libary lodash and i tried the function filter. But its not working. What I make wrong?

```
            results = await Promise.all(promiseArr);

            const data = lodash.filter(results, {
                listed: true
            });

            console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you will have multiple elements in the inner arrays, but this will work regardless.

```
const yourArray = [
  [
    {
      address: 'x-x-x-x',
      listed: false
    },
    {
      address: '1-x-x-x',
      listed: true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      address: '2-x-x-x',
      listed: true
    }
  ]
]

const newArray = yourArray.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const listedTrueObjects = currentValue.filter(obj => {
    return obj.listed === true
  })
  previousValue = previousValue.concat(listedTrueObjects)
  return previousValue
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

EDIT: didn't see your lower code...this should work.

```
results = await Promise.all(promiseArr);

const data = results.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const listedTrueObjects = currentValue.filter(obj => {
    return obj.listed === true
  })
  previousValue = previousValue.concat(listedTrueObjects)
  return previousValue
}, [])

console.log(results);
```